# Fix vim status line, it does not color > and < areas

Tags: vim

My vim status line does not color the > and < symbols correctly. Attached the same. Can anyone explain what is going on?

[image]

Comment: Without any information about how you are setting `'statusline'` and which plugins you are using it is hard to provide any help.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will check the `statusline` and see if some plugin is changing it.

Comment: I guess its just a theming problem. This guy had the same problem https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/pull/24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to install [powerline-fonts](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline#integrating-with-powerline-fonts)

Alternatively, put this in your .vimrc to hide the seperators

```
let g:airline_left_sep=''
let g:airline_right_sep=''
```